# Why my .pagnation li add active not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to add class active to my pagination, the purpose is to allow user  to know which page number they are looking at. However, it does not seem to work properly.

Any one have any idea?

I create the pagnation using php.

```
echo"<div align='center'>  
        <ul class='pagination'>";
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($productArr[$catCode]) / 4 + 1; $i++) {
            echo"<li><a href='collectionPage.php?cat={$catCode}&page={$i}'> {$i}</a></li>
         ";
        }

        echo"<li><a href='collectionSummary.php?cat={$catCode}'>view all</a></li>";

        echo"</ul>
        </div>";
```

Function I used

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var pageItem = $(".pagination li");

            pageItem.click(function () {
                pageItem.removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using javascript to modify the page when the user clicks on a link.  This might work for a couple of milliseconds, but when the page is reloaded at the new link, anything from the previous page load will be lost.  (This is true unless you're loading pages through AJAX, and have got an "ajaxify" plugin or something to prevent links from working as normal, but I doubt that is the case?)

What you want to do is have your server-side code set the "active" class when it first renders the page.  Something along the lines of:

```
$currentPage = 3;
for ($i = 1; $i < count($productArr[$catCode]) / 4 + 1; $i++) {
    $activeOrNotClass = "";
    if ($i == $currentPage)
        $activeOrNotClass = "active";
    echo"<li class='" + $activeOrNotClass + "' ><a href='collectionPage.php?cat={$catCode}&page={$i}'> {$i}</a></li>";
}
```

(obviously, you must set the value of $currentPage as appropriate)

Comment: Thanks, really helps me to understand the problem better

Answer (score 1):

The click must be transferred to your `a` tag.

Try with something like this:

```
var pageItem = $(".pagination li");

pageItem.on('click', 'a', function () {
    pageItem.removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

See a sample JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/q8de0nt1/

However, as you are loading another page, you will have to add the "active" class to the correct `<li>` item through PHP code, when rebuilding the pagination menu

Answer (score 0):

try with **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).on("click",".pagination li",function () {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
               $(this).addClass("active");
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it does not seem to work. The class is active for a split second then in-active again. However, if i click the page for multiple times, the class will be active. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: because default `class='active'` not  present with in element.Its a syntax error of removeClass

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will do more research on that.

Comment: check this, same as the first answer. but i'm not applying the next prev function yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482739/how-to-get-my-prev-and-next-button-work-on-pagination

Comment: Are you try with `.prev()`,`.next()` with `on()` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131970/discussion-between-chen-jian-and-prasad).

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate event in jquery by listening on the parent .pagination not on an individual li or a element and here's how to do so :

```
  `// remove acitve class for all li
  $('.pagination').children('li').removeClass('active');
//add initial active class
$('.pagination').children('li').first().addClass('active');
$( ".pagination" ).on( "click", "li", function() {
var $this = $(this);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass("active");

});`
```